# Shorthand for defining Python functions that are the same?

Tags: python, function

If I have many variables I want to initialize with the same value, I use:

```
a = b = c = ""
```

Is there a similar shorthand for defining many functions that do the same thing? That is, neither of the following works:

```
def x() = y() = z():
def x() = def y() = def z():
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply assign functions like you would assign variables.

```
def z():
  whatever

x = y = z
```

You can't do it in one line if you want to use `def`, but if you can make it into a `lambda` you can make a one-liner:

```
x = y = z = lambda foo: bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def z():
    pass

x = y = z
```

Comment: Dear Tom: I think you misread the question. As in, you didn't read the question. With love, Santiago.

Comment: Actually, something strange happened in my formatting and the second part of my answer was cut off. Hooray for screwing up my first ever answer!

Comment: Haha welcome to SO! may your future answers address the question! :P

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... functions are also objects, so you can do this:

```
def foo():
   pass

bar = foo
```

As you can see, the syntax is the same.

Why would you WANT to, hell if I know.

Answer (score 0):

you can do soemthing like this:

```
def X():
    pass

Y = Z = X
```

Comment: Function names should be lowercase; ProperCase is for class names.